# Php. Find the most recent items in the branch that are not parents

Tags: php, tree, parent

The table structure sql (id, title, parent_id):

[table structure](http://storage9.static.itmages.com/i/18/0203/h_1517699086_4631523_91b2c06c53.jpeg)

Can you please tell us how to find records on PHP that are not parents. They are the last in the menu tree. Only cycles and functions can be used.

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOffQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM table)
```

Comment: Such a query is not suitable, because it chooses the same sub_menu 1,
sub_menu 2.  https://ibb.co/nB4BUR